# Why does Nmap behavior vary depending on how the scanning machine is connected to the Internet?

Tags: nmap

I tried to scan one of the routers in our office from a virtual machine connected to a different router.

When the virtual machine is connected to the Internet (directly?) Nmap gives up straight away

[image]

[image]

but when the virtual machine is connected using a NAT Nmap switches to SYN scan?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

nmap performs scans only upon the online hosts it finds online from the  host list given as input, 
In your case 2 nmap is able to find the host online by default probing method that is ICMP which was allowed by your router ACLs

in first case no scan is performed because Default probing method does not find any host up, because your non nated ip is not allowed in router ACL to perform ICMP requests

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you care to simplify it a little bit for me? I am not sure I completely understand it

Comment: before switching to port scan on a host , Nmap check whether the host is up . one of the way is to check ICMP . so it seems in your case that namp didnt find host up in case vm is directly attached to internet , so please check your router accesslists

Comment: any idea why? the host is up

Comment: i already mention it that ICMP probes might be failing ... run nmap with switch --packet-trace

Comment: nmap <option> < ip >  --packet-trace

Comment: The default set of host discovery ("ping") probes is more than just ICMP. It is "an ICMP echo request, a TCP SYN packet to port 443, a TCP ACK packet to port 80, and an ICMP timestamp request." (https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html)

Comment: you are absolutly correct .  but  if server is not a web server , not entertaining a request at 443 then probing 443 is useless . similarly a direct ack is never enertained by secure sservers .. so we are left with ICMP to go with